# POST Nested Json. But getting empty

Tags: rest, dropwizard, postman

I am trying to send a POST request which is of the form :

```
{
"startTime":"2014-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
"endTime":"2014-12-03T00:00:00.000Z",
"numRows":200,
"object":{
         "key":"I am having trouble parsing you",
         "key2":"value2"
         }

}
```

At the backend (using dropwizard), my resource class is defined as:

```
    class ResourceExample{

    public Response process(SearchQuery q){

    //doing something
//here q.object = {} instead of {"key": "I am having trouble parsing you", "key2" : "value2"} 
    }

    }

    class SearchQuery{


        @NotNull
        JSONObject object;
        @NotNull
        String startTime;
        @NotNull
        String endTime;
        @NotNull
        int numRows;

    //getters and setters present.

    }
```

Now when I POST the request, the value of "object" is  {}.
I am expecting it to be {"key": "I am having trouble parsing you", "key2": "value2" }

Please help me here. I am sure there is something I am missing. Something that is not clicking in my mind. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer on the assumption that you are using dropwizard.

First, in my environment , that code gets the following error

```
{
  message: "Unrecognized field "key" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable"
}
```

The code following:

ResourceExample.java

```
@Path("/sample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResourceExample {

    @POST
    public void process(SearchQuery q) {
    ...
```

SearchQuery.java

```
public class SearchQuery{
    private JSONObject object;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private int numRows;
    //getters and setters present.
    ...
```

And to work, I change to the next code:

SearchQuery.java

```
 -  private JSONObject object;
 +  private Map<String, Object> object;
```

This , each of these keys and values into the map.

If you want `{"key": "I am having trouble parsing you", "key2": "value2" }`, you can do the next code.

```
new JSONObject(q.getObject()).toString()
```

Comment: Thanks. When nobody responded to my question, i eventually figured out myself. I did the same thing you did above.

I will accept yours as the right solution. Thanks again!